# Restructure JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to restructure the JSON array in following manner. In the output, I need `id` as key and object itself as it's value.

Sample input:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "1-1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "1-1-1",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1-1-2",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "1-2",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "3-1",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Required output:

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "children": {
            "1-1": {
                "id": "1-1",
                "children": {
                    "1-1-1": {
                        "id": "1-1-1",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    "1-1-2": {
                        "id": "1-1-2",
                        "children": []
                    }
                }
            },
            "1-2": {
                "id": "1-2",
                "children": []
            }
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "children": []
    },
    "3": {
        "id": "3",
        "children": {
            "3-1": {
                "id": "3-1",
                "children": []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following code gives me almost the required answer.

```
function restruct(arr) {
    var newArray = arr.map(function(obj) {
        var t = {};
        if (obj.children)
            obj.children = restruct(obj.children);
        t[obj.id] = obj;
        return t;
    });
    return newArray;
}
```

The output is:

```
[
    {
        "1": {
            "id": "1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "1-1": {
                        "id": "1-1",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "1-1-1": {
                                    "id": "1-1-1",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "1-1-2": {
                                    "id": "1-1-2",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "1-2": {
                        "id": "1-2",
                        "children": []
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "2": {
            "id": "2",
            "children": []
        }
    },
    {
        "3": {
            "id": "3",
            "children": [
                {
                    "3-1": {
                        "id": "3-1",
                        "children": []
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

If you notice, everything is as per expected output except the `children` nodes. It returns array of objects while I need object with key-value pairs. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Curious what is wrong or problematic with using current structure? Seems more code friendly to me

Comment: @charlietfl, A JavaScript library I'm using requires above format as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `map` because it returns an array, you can use `forEach` instead, like:

```
function restruct(arr) {
    var result = {};

    arr.forEach(function(obj) {         
        if (obj.children) {
            obj.children = restruct(obj.children);
        }

        result[obj.id] = obj;
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function restruct(arr) {
    var result = {};

    arr.forEach(function(obj) {         
        if (obj.children) {
            obj.children = restruct(obj.children);
        }

        result[obj.id] = obj;
    });
    return result;
}
```