# Convert PHP Associate Array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to convert below PHP Associate Array like this

**Input:**

```
array(
        array(
            ""=> "Col A",
            "Row A"=> 5,
            "Row B"=> 2,                 
        ),
        array(
            ""=> "Col B",
            "Row A"=> 4,
            "Row B"=> 5,                  
        ),
        array(
            ""=> "total",
            "Row A"=> 7,     // "A's total"
            "Row B"=> 9,     // "B's total"              
        ),
        array(
            ""=> "average",
            "Row A"=> 3.5,    
            "Row B"=> 4.5,                  
        )
    )
```

In above **Row** are fixed while **Col** are dynamic.

And Need to convert it into

**Output :**

```
[
    {
        type: "Row A",
        percent: 7,
        subs: [
                {
                    type: "Col A",
                    percent: 5
                }, 
                {
                    type: "Col B",
                    percent: 2
                }
            ]
    }, 
    {
        type: "Row B",
        percent: 9,
        subs: [
                {
                    type: "Col A",
                    percent: 4
                }, 
                {
                    type: "Col B",
                    percent: 5
                }
            ]
    }
]
```

I tried to code different iterative solution but couldn't get this type of solution and is very complex in terms of iteration.

Comment: Are these dynamic? As in, there could be more than just A & B? Do you always know how many of these elements are present?

Comment: @El_Vanja , Yes

Comment: `""=> "Col A",`,`""=> "Col B",` is looking a bit suspicious.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I was making few changes. Now above is the exact issue.

Comment: Still same. As well as The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you have control over the input array's format I'de try to make that more reliable/consistent.

Comment: @Maqsud  Not only that you completely missed out `average` array in your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by encoding the array in JSON format.

Here's the sample code for your better understanding:

```
<?php
$names = array(
        array(
            "foo"=> "bar",
        ),
        array(
            "foo"=> "bar",
        ),
        array(
            "foo"=> "bar",
        ),
    );
$namesJSON = json_encode($names);
echo "<pre>";
echo $namesJSON;
echo "</pre>"; 

?>
```

This will output the JSON array which is required. Hope this answers your question. In order to generate the required JSON structure, you can read more about it on [this](https://jsfiddle.net/swgf8sxu/1/) JS Fiddle and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997827/restructure-json-array) stack overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to rearrange in PHP. The code snippet works with cols and rows being dynamic. Only average and total are assumed to be present, while average is not being used and only removed to prevent it act like another data-column.

```
$input = array(
    array(
        ""      => "Col A",
        "Row A" => 5,
        "Row B" => 2,
    ),
    array(
        ""      => "Col B",
        "Row A" => 4,
        "Row B" => 5,
    ),
    array(
        ""      => "total",
        "Row A" => 7,     // "A's total"
        "Row B" => 9,     // "B's total"              
    ),
    array(
        ""      => "average",
        "Row A" => 3.5,
        "Row B" => 4.5,
    )
);

//Rearrange to data in columns
$columns = array_column($input, null,'');

//Extract total/average Columns and remove from dataset
$total = $columns['total'];
unset($columns['total']);
$average = $columns['average'];
unset($columns['average']);

//Extract information about rows present in first dataset
$rows = array_filter(array_keys($input[0]));

//Rearrange for output
$output = [];
foreach($rows as $row){
    $rowOutput = ['type'=>$row, 'percent'=>$total[$row],'subs'=>[]];
    foreach($columns as $col => $colData){
        $rowOutput['subs'][] = ['type'=>$col,'percent'=>$colData[$row]];
    }
    $output[] = $rowOutput;
}

//json encode here if you need it
print json_encode($output,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ecfe52ace4bfe149d0d354b6156b73401344aaf3

Comment: What about `average` array in your desired output. Op must have to correct input and output array first to get concrete solution.

Comment: The average data is currently not used. (as per question / desired output). As this question is abstract and i have no clue why / where / what this data is good for i assume he is not needing the average in the output.

But you could easily add it if you wish so:

       $rowOutput = ['type'=>$row, 'percent'=>$total[$row], 'average'=>$average[$row],'subs'=>[]];