# How to merge two arrays diferents on one

Tags: php

How to update an array of objects, adding the quantities if you already have the same ID, or if you have not created a new object.

I tried to explain in the code with the arrays and also with the idea of how I would like the result to be.

old Array

```
$a1 = [
    array(
        "id" => 1,
        "qty" => 1
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 2,
        "qty" => 1
    )
];

$a2 = [
    array(
        "id" => 1,
        "qty" => 1
    )
];

$output = array_merge($a1, $a2);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
```

Result Error:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [qty] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [qty] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [qty] => 1
        )

)
```

What I need, in addition to if the ID does not contain, add.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [qty] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [qty] => 1
        )   
)
```

Comment: Do you want to encode it in json format? if yes? then this can help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66077071/7698734

Comment: @HassaanAli No, results in php.

Comment: you want the result in plain php? no json?

Comment: @HassaanAli Yes in php array, I need to record this in Wordpress.

Comment: use php function array merge function to merge them. here's the sample code for you. 

` <?php
$a1=array("red","green");
$a2=array("blue","yellow");
print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
?>`

This will print the two arrays in single array format.

Comment: @HassaanAli It doesn't work, because I have different keys (id = product), in addition to having to add the 'qty' key

Comment: An easy approach could be to loop and rename the `id` key to `product` if you encounter the key `id`. (And update corresponding values if it already exists)

Comment: @Remy Even so, the array_merge command duplicates the ID key.

Comment: Why would you need array merge? Also what is your intention with price? I see the total qty is updated but there are 2 different prices though.

Comment: Ready I updated the arrays, it was simpler,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the first array as base, then search for the key (if existing) where the `product` matches the `id`. Then either add the quantity and recalculate the price or you just add the reformatted element (`id` to `product` conversion).

```
$result = $a;
foreach($b as $element) {
    $matchingProductIndex = array_search($element['id'], array_column($a, 'product'));
    if ($matchingProductIndex !== false) {
        $pricePerUnit = $result[$matchingProductIndex]['price'] / $result[$matchingProductIndex]['qty'];
        $result[$matchingProductIndex]['qty'] += $element['qty'];
        $result[$matchingProductIndex]['price'] = $result[$matchingProductIndex]['qty'] * $pricePerUnit;
    } else {
        $result[] = [
            'qty' => $element['qty'],
            'product' => $element['id'],
            'price' => $element['price'],
        ];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/GsM2e).

Comment: top very very  thanx

Answer (score 1):

Loop through both arrays with foreach and check the ids against each other.
https://paiza.io/projects/lnnl5HeJSFIOz_6KD6HRIw

```
<?php

$arr1 = [['qty' => 4, 'id' => 4],['qty' => 1,'id' => 30]];
$arr2 = [['id' => 30, 'qty' => 19],['id' => 31, 'qty' => 2]];
$arr3 = [];
foreach($arr1 as $iArr1){
    $match = false;
    foreach($arr2 as $iArr2){
        if($iArr1['id'] === $iArr2['id']){
           $arr3[] = ['id' => $iArr1['id'], 'qty' => $iArr1['qty'] + $iArr2['qty']];
           $match = true;
        }
    }
    if(!$match){
        $arr3[] = $iArr1;
        $arr3[] = $iArr2;
    }
}

print_r($arr3);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be one I more often suggested.
First lets merge `$a2` with one to simplify looping over one larger collection.
If we then create a small mapping from `id` to its index in the result array we can update the running total of `qty`.

```
$map = [];
$result = [];

// Merge the two and do as per usual, create a mapping
// from id to index and update the qty at the corresponding index.
foreach (array_merge($a1, $a2) as $subarr) {
    $id = $subarr['id'];

    if (!key_exists($id, $map)) {
        $index = array_push($result, $subarr) - 1;
        $map[$id] = $index;

        continue;
    }

    $result[$map[$id]]['qty'] += $subarr['qty'];
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($result, true), '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [qty] => 2
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [qty] => 1
        )
)
```